# What is the cause of this error? Code was working before and randomly started to error out

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, apache-sedona

I am writing pyspark code to get geo census results and the code below was working as expected. However, now I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o137.showString.
: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:83)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$$resolveTry(Promise.scala:75)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$.apply(Promise.scala:402)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$.fromTry(Promise.scala:138)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$.failed(Promise.scala:124)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.failed(Future.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.$anonfun$materializeFuture$1(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.LazyValue.getOrInit(LazyValue.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.Exchange.getOrInitMaterializeFuture(Exchange.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.materializeFuture(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.materialize(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.materialize$(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.materialize(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ShuffleQueryStageExec.doMaterialize(QueryStageExec.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExec.$anonfun$materialize$1(QueryStageExec.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExec.materialize(QueryStageExec.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.MaterializeExecutable.tryStart(AdaptiveExecutable.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutorRuntime.startChild(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ExecutionHelper.start(ExecutionHelper.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.QueryStageExecutable$$anon$2.$anonfun$new$1(AdaptiveExecutable.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ExecutionHelper$Listener.$anonfun$onChildSuccess$2(ExecutionHelper.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ExecutionHelper$Listener.$anonfun$onChildSuccess$2$adapted(ExecutionHelper.scala:54)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ExecutionHelper$Listener.$anonfun$onChildSuccess$1(ExecutionHelper.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ExecutionHelper$Listener.$anonfun$onChildSuccess$1$adapted(ExecutionHelper.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.ExecutionHelper$Listener.onChildSuccess(ExecutionHelper.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutorRuntime.$anonfun$onActiveChildSuccess$2(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutorRuntime.$anonfun$onActiveChildSuccess$2$adapted(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:314)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutorRuntime.onActiveChildSuccess(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutorRuntime.onChildSuccess(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutor.$anonfun$doRun$1(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutor.$anonfun$doRun$1$adapted(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:145)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:235)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutor.doRun(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutor.tryRunningAndGetFuture(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveExecutor.execute(AdaptiveExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$getFinalPhysicalPlan$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.getFinalPhysicalPlan(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:404)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2762)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3724)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2762)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2969)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:339)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.sedona.core.utils.SedonaConf.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/SparkConf;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.doExecute(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.TraitJoinQueryExec.doExecute$(TraitJoinQueryExec.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.strategy.join.RangeJoinExec.doExecute(RangeJoinExec.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDD(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.inputRDDs(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:746)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDD(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:746)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.inputRDD(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture$lzycompute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.mapOutputStatisticsFuture(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.$anonfun$materializeFuture$2(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeLike.$anonfun$materializeFuture$1(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:100)
    ... 76 more
```

screenshots of the c o d e are below

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfy2e.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxrBY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxhZl.png)

I was expecting to see the first 20 rows of the dataframe

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.sedona.core.utils.SedonaConf.<init>`

The above suggests some dependency change in the underlying execution environment. What environment are you running this code on?

Comment: @ankush1377 I am running this is in AWS glue. I set the spark config to use sedona. So would this be a change on the sedona side or aws's version of spark?